# Get the last meeting date from Google Calendar using guest email address

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail, google-calendar-api

I need a method in which I can scan through previous meetings (this can go months back) in Google Calendar and find the last meeting (Google Calendar event) with a person (email address) and the number of meetings I've had with them.

Searching in the documentation: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar

There is no method to find events by email. The result I would need returned is the date of last meeting and count of total meetings including that person.

Has anyone done anything like that? I would greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: In your question, `meetings` are events in a calendar?

Comment: @Tanaike Correct. Sorry, I should have specified. Will edit it.

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your question, you want to retrieve all events in a calendar using an email of the guest, and you want to retrieve the latest event and the number of events. Is my understanding correct? If my understanding is correct, can I ask you about the latest event you want to retrieve. In this case, it's the event ID or other values?

Answer (score 2):

You can specify a search query using [`getEvents()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#geteventsstarttime,-endtime,-options), then use [`getGuestByEmail()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event#getGuestByEmail(String)) and [`getGuestStatus()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/event-guest#getGuestStatus()) to check if you met with them.

```
function getLastEventWith(contactEmail) {
  const events = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar() // Doesn't have to be the default calendar
    .getEvents(new Date(1970, 0, 1), new Date(), { search: contactEmail })
    .reverse(); // Events are sorted earliest-to-latest, so reverse
  
  let total = 0;
  let lastEvent;
  for (let event of events) {
    const guest = event.getGuestByEmail(contactEmail);
    if (guest.getGuestStatus() === CalendarApp.GuestStatus.YES || guest.getGuestStatus() === CalendarApp.GuestStatus.OWNER) {
      if (total === 0) {
        lastEvent = event;
      }
      total++;
    }
  }
  return { lastEvent: lastEvent, total: total };
}


function test_getLastEventWith() {
  const { lastEvent, total } = getLastEventWith("someone@example.com");
  console.log(lastEvent.getTitle());
  console.log(lastEvent.getStartTime());
  console.log(total);
}
```

You may be able to do this with fewer calls by using the [Calendar Advanced Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/calendar).